# Modbus floating point conversion

Tags: arduino, communication, modbus

I am using Arduino modbus library for measuring string current using hall sensor.Here library downloaded.[Modbus library](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/tree/master/examples) .I have sensor data in floating value & the library store the value in integer format.

question :

1. how can save the sensor value into integer format
2. How can assign user defined address. start address like 4000h instead of 0000H

code

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include"glob.h"
//#define ID   1
void Device_ID_Reading()
{
  for(row=0;row<9;row++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SO_enable,array1[row][0]);
    digitalWrite(S1_enable,array1[row][1]);
    digitalWrite(S2_enable,array1[row][2]); 
    Status_Out[row]=digitalRead(Read_IDstatus);
    Device_ID =1*Status_Out[0]+2*Status_Out[1]+4*Status_Out[2]+8*Status_Out[3]+16*Status_Out[4]+32*Status_Out[5]+64*Status_Out[6]+128*Status_Out[7];
    Serial.print("Device_ID"); 
    Serial.print(row); 
    Serial.print(":\t");
    Serial.println(Device_ID);

  }
}


int8_t state = 0;
Modbus slave(Device_ID, 0, 0);
unsigned long tempus;
// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[30];

void Take_Reading()
{
  for(row=0;row<9;row++)
  {
    //  int k=(8*array[row][0]+4*array[row][1]+2*array[row][2]+1*array[row][3]);
    //   digitalWrite(Enablepin,array[row][0]);
    digitalWrite(SO_enable,array1[row][1]);
    digitalWrite(S1_enable,array1[row][2]);
    digitalWrite(S2_enable,array1[row][3]); 
    //delay(100); 
    Sensor_Value0=analogRead(A0);
    Sensor_Value1=analogRead(A5);
    Mux1_array[row]=(Sensor_Value0 * ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING);
    Mux2_array[row]=(Sensor_Value1 * ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING);

    Current_Value1[row]=  (Mux1_array[row]*35.1428571429)-87.6571428571;
    Current_Value2[row]=  (Mux2_array[row]*35.1428571429)-87.6571428571;
    Current_Value3[row]=(Mux3_array[row]*35.1428571429)-87.6571428571;

  }
}
void setup()
{
  wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);
  slave.begin( 9600 );
  tempus = millis() + 100;
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SO_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 7 of arduino
  pinMode(S1_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 6 of arduino
  pinMode(S2_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 5 of arduino
  //  pinMode(Enablepin, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 4 of arduino
  pinMode(A0, INPUT) ;
  pinMode(A1, INPUT) ;
  pinMode(A2,INPUT);
  //  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  // wdt_reset();
  Take_Reading();
  Device_ID_Reading(); 
  state = slave.poll( au16data,30 );
  if (state > 4) {
    tempus = millis() + 50;
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  if (millis() > tempus) digitalWrite(13, LOW );

  Modbus_call();

}
void Modbus_call()
{

  /*reading of coil where i can succefully read value*/
  au16data[1]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[0]);
  au16data[2]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[1]);
  au16data[3]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[3]);
  au16data[4]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[4]);
  au16data[5]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[5]);
  au16data[6]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[6]);
  au16data[7]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[7]);
  au16data[8]=(int)(100*Current_Value1[8]); 
  au16data[9]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[0]);
  au16data[10]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[1]);  
  au16data[11]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[2]);
  au16data[12]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[3]);
  au16data[16]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[4]);
  au16data[17]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[5]);
  au16data[18]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[6]);
  au16data[19]=(int)(100*Current_Value2[7]);
  uint16_t calcCRC( au16data[15]);
  au16data[13] = slave.getInCnt();
  au16data[14] = slave.getOutCnt();
  au16data[15] = slave.getErrCnt(); 

}
```

**Is there any other library where i can use the floating point directly.**

Answer (score 0):

Modbus as a protocol does not directly support floats. However you can put float data into adjacent registers. Use [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) to put the float data into your registers and pull it out on the other side.

```
union Pun {float f; uint32_t u;};

void encodeFloat(uint16_t *regs, float x)
{
    union Pun pun;

    pun.f = x;
    regs[0] = (pun.u >> 16) & 0xFFFFU;
    regs[1] = pun.u & 0xFFFFU;
}

float decodeFloat(const uint16_t *regs)
{
    union Pun pun;

    pun.u = ((uint32_t)regs[0] << 16) | regs[1];
    return pun.f;
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
void Modbus_call()
{
    /*reading of coil where i can succefully read value*/
    encodeFloat(&au16data[ 0],  Current_Value1[0]);
    encodeFloat(&au16data[ 2],  Current_Value1[1]);
    encodeFloat(&au16data[ 4],  Current_Value1[2]);
    /* And so on... */
}
```